# Runtastic API: get activity route coordinates

Tags: api

I've been wondering, is there any way to get route coordinates(lat,long) of the Runtastic activity, like in the other run-tracking apps (Runkeeper, Mapmyrun and so on)?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the overview of your activities, select year and month of your interest on the left side, then open the debug console of your browser and paste in following Code if you want to export all Activities of a year or month:

```
$('#sumtable tbody tr').not('.distance_0').each(function () {
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(frame);
    frame.style = 'width: 1px; height: 1px;';
    frame.src = $(this).find('a').attr('href') + '.tcx';
});
```

If you are only interestet in a specific activity, you can open the activity in your Browser and just append the file extension ".tcx", ".gpx" or ".kml" to the url.